# React call api when component is rendered runs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been studying react and searching and didn't find any answer for this.
So I have this component that calls my api to know what to do when it is rendered.
The problem is that it is rendered twice, and I wanted to know if that is ok because I'm telling the component to update itself or if I'm doing something wrong.
From what I've searched I see that the render runs if the setState is called, but I still find this a bit odd, maybe it's because I'm new to React but I would like to clear things out.

Example:

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color:'none',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateColor();
  }

  updateColor() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { color: 'red'}
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("potatoes");
    return (
      <div>        
        <h1>Car color: {this.state.color}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/jorgemdss/pen/qBEqroE?editors=0010

If you open dev tools you see that "potatoes" are logged twice.
Is it completely normal or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You are setting state on `componentDidMount` when you update state component is re-rendered unless you make use of `shouldComponentUpdate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is completly normal.

The first render is when the component mounts and the second one is when it runs `componentDidMount` and calls `updateColor` which updates the state and render it again.

You probably don't see but your component will render `none` and after `red`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :)  
I noticed what you are saying and it makes sense, just didn't know about the re-rendering but it all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 3):

It is normal as in first render it renders with value as 'none' and on the second render it renders with value as 'red'.

You will see that the component renders only once if you comment out `setState`.

When you run this code you will see the log as follows.

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color:'none',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateColor();
  }

  updateColor() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { color: 'red'}
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.color); //change potatoes to this.state.color
    return (
      <div>        
        <h1>Car color: {this.state.color}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Console.log

```
"none"
"red"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that in to React, but after testing with your codepen, i think it is:
The first time the Code is executed is because the `React.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('app'));` Then after the State changes, the Page renders again automatically.

You can test this if you add `this.state.color` to the console.log and/ or commentOut the `setState`